# Can I change this '下‘ for '前面‘？

Tags: meaning

I have this in my text:

在绿色、环保已成为全社会共识的大背景下， 。。。

‘背景下’ says to me ‘under a background' which seems odd. I would rather locate things 'in front of' a background.

Can I change '背景下‘ for '背景前‘ or '背景前面‘ and still win the 'Impeccable Chinese Prize' ？？

Comment: Interesting. Is it a natural way to say `in front of` for `background` in English?

Comment: As Ringli pointed out below, this is a logic statement， not really a locative statement. I would translate ‘在这背景下’  with 'given this background'. The text above I would render as 'given that ecology and environmental protection are common knowledge in today's society, ...'
For locative statements 'before a background of' is good.

Answer (score 4):

No. The grammatical pattern is

> 在x下

which means "with x as true/under". An example would be:

> 在共产党的统治下，中国变强了。

So the sentence means something like (though it's kinda hard to translate this semi-literally without sounding very weird):

> With a green and environmental world as the consensus background for
>   society...

Comment: I know in Chinese we can say '在 blablabla 的情况下‘， just seems wierd to me to be 'under a background', not 'in front of' or 'before', because the natural opposite of 'back' is 'front'.

Comment: I think the correct way to think of it as "with x as a backdrop" as in with "x" in mind.

Comment: cf。介词，常用介词的用法 in any grammar，e。g。实用现代汉语语法１。在。。。上，２。在。。。中，３。在。。。下。＂在。。。下＂表示条件。中间多为名词短语或有定语的双音节动词。例如：１。在舅舅的劝说下，母亲卖了部分房子和土地，供我们读中学。２。在他的带领下，全乡农民已经脱贫致富，提前实现了小康。３。我们认为在社会主义制度下，积累和消费的关系，根本上是一致的。４。这些花灯、鱼灯是在老艺人的指点下，群众业余创作出来的。５。在老师和同学们的帮助下，小明进步了。

Answer (score 2):

No.

In Chinese, `下` should be used for an "abstract background", such as

> 在全球气候变暖的背景下
>   在当时的社会背景下
>   在互联网时代背景下

And `前` is usually used for a "concrete background", such as

> 办公室背景前歪着头拿着报纸的商务男士
>   灰色背景前的蝴蝶图片
>   如何在移动的背景前拍摄静态人物